# Ios go to next view using a button without using navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

just getting started with IOS - worked out a few tutorials -

Everything i have worked with in the tutorials - i have been using the navigation controller to go to the next view when clicking on a button.

well i was having a look at the logos quiz app by aticoD.

1. i cant see any navigation controller on this app- it has some custom arrow picture, that acts as a back button- but the navigation bar is not visible.

is it using this method ???-

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

--- you can see on the app, to choose level - you have to swipe -

can anyone give me a few guidelines on how to implement this part. or link me to a tutorial.

Comment: do you want swiping viewcontroller?

Comment: @RomitMewada i want to know how he has embedded the swiping feature in one viewcontroller. for example on the home view, you can swipe around the middle of the screen to see the different levels.

and i want to know how to use buttons to change view without using a navigation controller. thanks

Comment: i dont have idea without using navigationController. but i can give you example to swiping two viewcontoller with navigationController. if you want.

Comment: thanks, please show me the example

Answer (score 1):

you need to set this code

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//Animation 
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
 //animation add to layer.
[[viewController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pushAnimation"];

[[self.navigationViewController.view layer]addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pushAnimation"];
[self.navigationViewController pushViewController:seeAllViewController animated:YES];
```

for difference kind of animation you just need to change animation `Type`,`subType` and `fillMode`.

Comment: I found a video of the effect i am looking for 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUHWQPXGXmY

at 2:22 you will find exactly what i am looking for.